# How can I have links on my page that never move?

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph and header that are centered with css, and I have 5 different pages all with links that I've aligned to the very left of each page, with each link below eachother. But because I have text on each page, my links move down so they are uneven on every page, so basically the more text I have, the further down my links go.

Is there a way for me to just permanently keep my links in the same spot no matter what?

```css
.header a {
  color: rgb(235, 238, 205);
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1> Default Title </h1>
  <p>Temporary paragraph text.</p>
  <div class="header">
    <a href="Page 1">Test Page 1</a><br>
    <a href="Page 2">Test Page 2</a><br>
    <a href="Page 3">Test Page 3</a><br>
    <a href="Page 4">Test Page 4</a><br>
    <a href="Page 5">Test Page 5</a><br>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you don't want them to move with scrolling, there are actually many ways to do this. What you really want is a two column design. You can do this with CSS Grids, CSS Flex and more.

Answer (score 0):

You could use position: absolute. Like this:

```
.header { position: absolute; left: 0; }
```

You could then use left, right, top, bottom to set the exact position for your header div. If needed you could also add the z-index attribute, to position the header div above other elements.

If it should also stay in the same spot while scrolling use position: sticky. (Same attributes: top/bottom/...)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It just came to mind now but I just found a bunch of resources on creating a fixed sidebar. Would that be appropriate in this case also?

Comment: you should avoid using absolute positioning unless you really have to use it.  It's takes things out of the dom and makes it harder for the page to scale for different device sizes

Comment: Yes, he is right! Additionally to @DCR's response. You could also use a grid layout, but that is just one more answer out of many.

Answer (score 0):

lot's of ways to do this depending on what you really want to do.  inline-block seems like an obvious choice here

```css
.header a {
  color: rgb(235, 238, 205);
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}

.header{
   display:inline-block;
   width:15%;
   border:solid 1px red;
   }
   
   #container{
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:top;
   text-align:center;
   width:calc(85% - 8px);
   border:solid 1px green;
   }
```

```html
<body>

  <h1> Default Title </h1>
  
<div class="header">
  <a href="Page 1">Test Page 1</a><br>
  <a href="Page 2">Test Page 2</a><br>
  <a href="Page 3">Test Page 3</a><br>
  <a href="Page 4">Test Page 4</a><br>
  <a href="Page 5">Test Page 5</a><br>
</div>
<div id='container'>
  <p>Temporary paragraph text.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```